# Transform an expression to another with regex for a replace

Tags: regex

I need to replace a lot of strings in an application and I can do it with regex but I don't know how.

My current string is: `{$str.LOREM}` or `{$str.LOREM_IPSUM}`.

And the output desired is: `<?php echo i18n::n('example.lorem');?>` or `<?php echo i18n::n('example.lorem_ipsum');?>`.

**UPDATE:** Due to confussion in a answer: I want to do it with my IDE. I have like 500 different strings. Netbeans let me use regular expressions and I would like to find one that works with the above example. If possible if is not need to write all the 500 to change, it'll be beter. Thanks!

How I can do it?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use regex at all? You're looking for two particular strings, not a class of strings that have certain features in common, why can't you simply search for and replace them?

Answer (score 1):

If your string looks like that, you dont need regex, as that will be pretty slow. You can use the faster [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) method for that.

Its as simple as:

```
$content = str_replace('{$str.LOREM}', i18n::n('example.lorem'), $content);
$content = str_replace('{$str.LOREM_IPSUM}',i18n::n('example.lorem_ipsum'),$content);
```

Comment: but I want to do it with my IDE and not with PHP. And I've like 500 different strings, so I can't write one by one.

Comment: your question indicated it was with PHP. You should update your question to reflect you want to do it with your IDE.

Comment: it was not the mark, but the code snippet. I added the tag because you had the snippet in your question.